# "Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause." when doing SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE @Field LIKE @Record

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2010, oledb, vb.net-2010

```
Dim TableName As String
Dim ParamField As String
Dim ParamRecord As String
TableName = SearchBoxTableCmb.Text.ToString    (the value for SearchBoxTableCmb.Text.ToString is "User")
ParamField = SearchBoxFieldCmb.Text.ToString   (the value for SearchBoxFieldCmb.Text.ToString is "Username")
ParamRecord = SearchBoxTxt.Text                (the value for SearchBoxTxt.Text is "Cshort")
Oledb.AddParam("@Table", TableName)
Oledb.AddParam("@Field", ParamField)
Oledb.AddParam("@Record", ParamRecord)

DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE @Field LIKE @Record")
```

Below is the called Class

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Public Class OledbControl
Private OledbConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                         "Data Source = '" & Application.StartupPath & "\AS_Service_Database.accdb'")
Private OledbCmd As New OleDbCommand

Public OledbDataAdap As New OleDbDataAdapter
Public OledbDataSet As New DataSet
Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)
Public RecordCount As Integer
Public Exception As String

Public Function ExecQuery(Query As String) As Object
    Try
        OledbConn.Open()

        OledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, OledbConn)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(x) OledbCmd.Parameters.Add(x))
        Params.Clear()
        OledbDataSet = New DataSet
        OledbDataAdap = New OleDbDataAdapter(OledbCmd)
        OledbDataAdap.Fill(OledbDataSet, "TableName")
        Dim DataTable As DataTable = OledbDataSet.Tables("TableName")
        ExecQuery = DataTable

        OledbConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message

    End Try
    If OledbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then OledbConn.Close()
End Function

Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)

End Sub
```

End Class

I am trying to use a text box and a pair of combo boxes to search within a database but when i Execute the Query it creates the exception message
"Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause." But i cannot seem to find why what is wrong with the Query

Comment: are you sure all of your variables are not null or empty?

Comment: Please post the values which are being taken from the input boxes.

Comment: All Variables are assigned String Values and the values are  "User" "Username" and "Cshort" respectably

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind the table names or column names to a parameter. Instead, use the dynamic query combined from the variables, like this:

First of all, I think you need to extend your Oledb class with a new method:

```
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object, type As OleDbType)
    Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, type)
    NewParam.Value = Value
    NewParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    Params.Add(NewParam)
```

Then you need to call it passing the OleDbType.VarChar as type

```
Dim TableName As String
Dim ParamField As String
Dim ParamRecord As String
TableName = SearchBoxTableCmb.Text.ToString
ParamField = SearchBoxFieldCmb.Text.ToString
ParamRecord = SearchBoxTxt.Text
'you can bind to the value only
Oledb.AddParam("@Record", ParamRecord, OleDbType.VarChar) 

DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM [" & TableName & "] WHERE [" & ParamField & "] LIKE @Record")
```

Comment: okay, no longer is the Query Clause incomplete but there is now a 
"Syntax error in FROM clause."
Edit - Added square brackets before and after TableName concatination and it worked but didnt display any Records to the DataGrid

Comment: Put the `MsgBox("SELECT * FROM [" & TableName & "] WHERE [" & ParamField & "] LIKE @Record")` before the `DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQuery` line and show us what you see. BTW, try an updated answer

Comment: SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE '@Record
just to ask it only shows it as '@Record due to it not being in the Query Right???

Comment: there should not be an apostrophe before @Record. I.e. it needs to be `SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE @Record`. Where did apostrophe come from? You are right, the query should be with @Record, as it will be bound by the OleDb library

Comment: What is Oledb? How is it defined? Is AddParam method a custom function?

Comment: Just try to execute the `DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username LIKE 'Cshort'")`. If it works then I think the problem is with your AddParam method. You may need to introduce another one that takes an extra parameter to take the type

Comment: yeah it works when done as you suggested, any suggestions on adding parameters with data types

Comment: no errors, and compiles fine but still for some reason it generates no records

Comment: try to use VarWChar as the OleDbType when calling the AddParam method

Comment: still no records being returned :(

Comment: let's try one more thing. Let's add a '%' to the end of the parameter, like this: ParamRecord = SearchBoxTxt.Text + "%". Also, can you add this line: MsgBox ParamRecord to see what it is displaying.

Comment: It Displayed Cshort% but it showed no records...   Ps whether or not you find a fix youve been a massive help to me thankoo

 is there any chance that the way i am trying to display the records in the DataGrid is causing them not to display when parameters are used???

Comment: It makes no sense. Can you place a breakpoint in your ExecQuery function on this line `OledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, OledbConn)` and see if the parameters correctly added to the `OledbCmd.Parameters.` on the following line. Unless the Param list gets somehow deleted there should be now problems. Also check the OledbCmd.Parameters.Length after the executing of the ForEach lambda

Comment: i have resorted to not using parameters, i know it means the variables are able to be misused but 
DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQueryDataTable("SELECT * FROM [" & TableName & "] WHERE " & Field & " = '" & Record & "'")
works fully other than showing the column Access_Level of data type string which can be worked around i guess

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the field and table values into your string as non-parameter values using string.Format() or something like that. Right now, your query output will be

```
SELECT * FROM 'TABLE_VALUE' WHERE 'FIELD_VALUE' LIKE 'RECORD_VALUE'
```

Make sure when applying those values that you are sanitizing your data.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you should put between quotes the parameter you are using with the LIKE:

```
DataGrid.DataSource = Oledb.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE @Field LIKE '@Record'")
```